# Excel - get the average value of data in column B when they correspond to a specific time-interval

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, analytics, data-management

I have a set of data which is similar to the table below.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 12:00 | 200 |
| 12:30 | 235 |
| 12:45 | 233 |
| 12:55 | 245 |
| 13:09 | 265 |
| 13:15 | 288 |
| 13:35 | 289 |
| 13:55 | 299 |

What I need is to set a formula which allows me to get the max value from column B for each 1 hr interval in column A. For example, from 12:00 to 12:55 the max value is 245. From 13:09 to 13:55 the max value is 299.

In this way I can create another table where I will have in one column the 1st hr interval and in another column the correspondent max value for that hour.

Since I have an extensive amount of data, how can make this easier with a formula?

Thanks

I did this manually, but it takes too long.

Comment: Have you tried using `MAXIFS` yet?

Comment: Yes, but I still need to set the interval time manually. I would like something where I can drag the whole column (rather than dragging down for each hour) and the formula can read each hour and give me the max of that interval.

Answer (score 0):

Copy, paste, and update A3:B35 in the formula with your array:

```
=LET(
    data, A3:B35,
    a, TAKE(data, , 1),
    b, DROP(data, , 1),
    ua, UNIQUE(HOUR(a)),
    HSTACK(ua, MAP(ua, LAMBDA(m, MAX(FILTER(b, HOUR(a) = m)))))
)
```

[image: Picture Reference]

Comment: Thanks! Thank works!! How can I do the same but also adding a third column where I also have days and I want to have something like For this Day (column A), The first hr (column B), I have this max value (column C)

Comment: If you need to preserve date as well as hour of day but drop fractions of hour, you can use `FLOOR.MATH(a, 1/24)` instead of `HOUR(a)`.

Comment: If you wanted 15 minute intervals instead of hour intervals you could use `FLOOR.MATH(a, 1/96)`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a summary by hour, you can use a Pivot Table. Put the time column in the Rows area of the Pivot Table (as of at least Excel 2016, Excel will automatically generate a Hours field calculated from a time field added to pivot table rows or columns), but the values column in the Values area of the Pivot Table. Change "Summarize value field by" to "Max" in the "Value Field Settings" Dialog.

[image: Pivot Table Fields]

[image: Value Field Settings]

[image: Pivot Table Summarizing Max Value by Hour]

Comment: This is great! what if I also need to get a value every 15 mins?

Comment: I'm not sure that the ease of summarizing by hour in a Pivot Table extends to 15 minute intervals. Certainly using a formulas rather than Pivot Tables provides more flexibility.